# Building diagramming tool on Netbeans platform

Tags: java, netbeans, frameworks, diagramming

does anyone kvow what would be a good framework/library/tool to build a diagramming tool on top of Netbeans RCP platform.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah would love to know if there is something swing based we could use to create nodes and connect lines besides charting. For instance if i wanted to do some visio like application...

Answer (score 1):

JFreeChart would be useful.

And take a look at the screenshots page of the NetBeans Platform for some inspiration:

http://platform.netbeans.org/screenshots.html